# Make WooCommerce filters 'stick'

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I'm new to WooCommerce..and I have my sidebar setup so that it lists the product categories and then also at the top provides the ability to apply filters. The filter works fine on the current page, but if the user clicks a different product category the filter is 'deactivated'. Is there not a way to have that filter stay on the whole time the user is browsing products in various categories? I want it to stay enabled until the user turns it off.

To me this seems like obvious functionality, as from a user perspective it would be annoying to have to turn it on each time I view a new category.

Am I just missing something to make this work? Or is there some kind of work around?

Thank you!